# CSS only paging with transition/transformation

Tags: css

Is there a way to implement something like this using CSS only (except for the button click handlers)?

Consider a paging panel:

`<<` `<` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `>` `>>`

When clicking the right `>` Button, I want to slide the entries `1` to `5`  to the left "behind" the `<<` `<` buttons and also  `6` `7` `8` `9` `10` should slide in from the right (starting from "behind" the `>` `>>` buttons).

The result then should be 
`<<` `<` `6` `7` `8` `9` `10` `>` `>>`

Same should work in the other direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "except for the button click handlers"? Does this mean javascript is an option but your looking for a solution using the least javascript possible? Also: Do you need exactly 10 pages in 2 groups on your pager or should the solution work with different numbers as well?

Comment: Yes, it should be using least javascript possible. It should work with e.g. 13 pages but split them into blocks 1-5, 6-10 and 11-13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General idea

The solution is to layout the page-links in one horizontal line. One way to achieve this is to put them in a list, set `display:inline` on the `<li>`s and `white-space:nowrap` on the `<ul>`.

Next you have to make sure that all but the first 5 links are hidden. This can be achieved by setting a fixed `width` in conjunction with `text-overflow:clip` and `overflow:hidden`. I have to admit, I eyeballed the value for the width.

The scrolling effect can be achieved by setting some attribute via javascript and in CSS use `transform: translateX()` and `transition: translateX` if the attribute has been set.

### The code

*Tested only with Chrome, I don't give any promise this code will work with any other browser*

```js
var pages = document.getElementById("pages")
var scroll = Number(pages.dataset.scroll);

function scrollLeft() {
  scroll += 1;
  pages.dataset.scroll = scroll;
}

function scrollRight() {
  scroll -= 1;
  pages.dataset.scroll = scroll;
}
```

```css
.pager a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 .25em;
}

.pager ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.pager ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#pages {
  width: 13.75em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  float: left;
}

#pages ul {
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

#pages[data-scroll='1'] ul {
  transform: translateX(-13.75em);
}
```

```html
<div class="pager">
  <ul class="prev-links">
    <li><a href="#">&lt;&lt;</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:scrollRight();">&lt;</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="pages" data-scroll="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="next-links">
    <li><a href="javascript:scrollLeft();">&gt;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Room for improvement

This code does not check any bounds. So each click on `<` or `>` will change the variable `scroll` whether it makes sense or not.

For each step, you will have to include a new directive, so if you have 3 steps (i.e. more than 10 pages), you will have to add

```css
#pages[data-scroll='2'] ul {
  transform: translateX(-27.5em);
}
```

and so on.

The links for `<<` and `>>` don't work, especially the latter is going to be a bit tricky (and might be impossible, if you don't know in advance, how many pages there are.

In general, to get this fully working, there will be a lot of hardcoding stuff.

As requested, this is the solution with the least JS I could think of, but to be honest, if you're using JS for the click-handlers anyway (and you have to because this can't be done without it), it would be way better to implement a few calculation and sanity-checks in javascript instead of looking for an almost-CSS-only solution.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer and example.